# What's the issue with the SQLite Update method?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

For some reason the update method will not change my SQLite Database values! Why?

```
for (int go = 0; go < assignmentList.size(); go++) {

        dateBefore = assignmentList.get(go).assignmentDate;
        assDaysUntilDue = assignmentList.get(go).assignmentDaysUntilDue;
        daysElapsed = dateNow - dateBefore;
        newDays = assDaysUntilDue - daysElapsed;


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_DAYS_UNTIL_DUE, 1);

        dataBase.update(DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_TABLE, values, DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_NUM + " = " + go, null);
```

//UP HERE ^^ just made values to change to 1 in case variables were giving issues, 
    //BUT even this didn't give me values of 1 down the column
    //second try to change the values...

```
        dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE " + DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_TABLE + " SET " + DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_ENTRY_DATE + " = " + 
                dateNow + " WHERE " +  DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_NUM + " = " +  go + ";");
            dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE " + DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_TABLE + " SET " + DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_DAYS_UNTIL_DUE + " = " + 
                newDays + " WHERE " +  DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_NUM + " = " +  go + ";");


        }
```

Comment: `WHERE datefield=2014-01-24` is not going to end up well...

Comment: There is no record where the assignment_num column has the same value (or the same type) as `go`.

Comment: " WHERE " +  DBRecordsLayer.ASSIGNMENT_NUM + " = " +  go  isn't this it??

Comment: Also the date is an into value, I made sure of it by casting millis as an int

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue:
As it wasn't a runtime problem, I found my issue to be the (go+1) problem. As the database ID values didn't necessarily start from '1', it would update values that didn't exist in the database anymore.